# PHP: Can someone explain the rules for instaniating a class/child class, in respect to the order of class declaration?

Tags: php, class, instance

I hope I'm using the correct terminology, if not, please comment and I'll correct.

---

#### #1: Works

Instantiate *before* class declaration

```
$x = new Abc;

class Abc {
    // code
}
```

---

#### #2: Doesn't Work

Instantiate *before* child class declaration (child declared *before* parent)

```
$x = new Xyz

class Xyz extends Abc {
    // code
}

class Abc {
    // code
}
```

---

#### #3: Works

Instantiate *before* child class declaration (child declared *after* parent)

```
$x = new Xyz

class Abc {
    // code
}

class Xyz extends Abc {
    // code
}
```

---

#### #4: Works

Instantiate *after* child class declaration (child declared *before* parent)

```
class Xyz extends Abc {
    // code
}

$x = new Xyz

class Abc {
    // code
}
```

---

#### Edit

The following quote is from an answer below by @artsylar. I don't know if my shared host has *autoloading* enabled, but I can't wrap my head around that quote in relation to the examples I've listed.

> Note:
>
> Unless autoloading is used, then classes must be defined before they
>   are used. If a class extends another, then the parent class must be
>   declared before the child class structure. This rule applies to
>   classes that inherit other classes and interfaces.

Comment: And where is the `Abc` class in the second example? You have to include this class first.

Comment: @redreggae I edited my Question to show more details.

Comment: Autoloading only affects scenarios where the classes are defined in separate files, where you would need an autoloader to automatically include the source files. It wouldn't make a difference when the classes are defined in a single file.

Answer (score 3):

I think this link can help you. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

> Note:
>
> Unless autoloading is used, then classes must be defined before they
>   are used. If a class extends another, then the parent class must be
>   declared before the child class structure. This rule applies to
>   classes that inherit other classes and interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, artsylar. I'd seen that, but it didn't make sense to me. @cbuckley, why'd you delete your comment? I wouldn't have understood that passage without your help!

Comment: @AKTed looking at your extra examples, it wasn't quite correct. It didn't really explain why your example #3 works! Going to do some deeper digging to answer that one.

Comment: @AKTed there are a [couple](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=19312) of [bugs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=6418) related to your question, but neither give any details on the internals that would explain why *any* of your examples work. In fact, I'd go as far as to say that they're all undefined behaviour and shouldn't be relied upon :-)